# Update package of anaconda python

Tags: python, version, updates, anaconda

I'm working with *python 3.4*. I use anaconda to install my data-science's packages and I need the statsmodels ***0.8*** :

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/statsmodels/

but on anaconda there is only the statsmodels  ***0.6*** :

https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/pkg-docs

And I really need to work with conda for the deployment.

Any idea of how can I have the ***0.8*** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF a package is available on PyPi, you can use

```
conda skeleton pypi package
```

to create a condo-recipe for that package, then

```
conda build package
conda install --use-local package
```

to build and install the package

Comment: Thank you. It barely work. I'm working on python 3.4 and the version is available on the 3.5. But I don't think I can do something for that ^^